# pixel value larger than 255 after using bicubic resizing (tf.image.resize_images)

Tags: image, resize, tensorflow

I first downsample an image by factor of 2 using tf.image.resize_images and then upsample it by factor 2 again using tf.image.resize_images, for these two operations, I used bicubic as the kernel, but the result image has some pixel values larger than 255 or smaller than 0, when I switched to using bilinear kernel, the result images is good. Any one knows the reason?  Thank you very much.

Comment: This could very well be a bug in the bicubic kernel implementation. I suggest you open a GitHub issue here : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues
Please include the image causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's an explanation for this issue here: [tensorflow image_resize mess up image on unknown image size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37032251/tensorflow-image-resize-mess-up-image-on-unknown-image-size#39339482)

You can use tf.saturate_cast(image, dtype=tf.uint8) on the float32 output of resize_images to get pixels between 0 and 255.